# Получение данных из справочников 1С

Tags: 1с

С 1С совершенно не знаком, поэтому могу ошибаться в терминах.
Задача: Получить данные телефона из справочника при помощи запроса.
Имеется справочник Контрагенты, у него есть реквизиты, пусть Имя, Фамилия.., но нет телефона. Но если перейти на вкладку форма, то есть Форма1. И на неё уже есть текстовое поле телефон. Как мне выдернуть его при помощи запроса?
Если я напишу 
Выбрать
    *
ИЗ
    Справочник.Контрагенты.Формы.Форма1
то произойдёт ошибка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не указали ни версию платформы 1С (7.7, 8.х), ни конфигурацию (типовая или самописная), поэтому могу сделать лишь предположение. Скорее всего, информация о телефоне (как и о других контактных данных контрагента) содержится в регистре сведений КонтактнаяИнформация (это отдельная таблица, связанная со справочником Контрагенты), следовательно, для того, чтобы получить оттуда информацию, в запросе нужно соединить таблицы левым соединением, примерно так:

```
"ВЫБРАТЬ
|   Контрагенты.Ссылка КАК Контрагент,
|   КонтактнаяИнформация.Представление КАК Телефон
|ИЗ
|   Справочник.Контрагенты КАК Контрагенты
|       ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ РегистрСведений.КонтактнаяИнформация КАК КонтактнаяИнформация
|       ПО КонтактнаяИнформация.Объект = Контрагенты.Ссылка
|ГДЕ
|   Контрагенты.Ссылка = &Ссылка"
```

Это упрощённый пример, в реальных типовых конфигурациях регистр сведений КонтактнаяИнформация, кроме ссылки на объект, содержит ещё такие измерения, как Тип и Вид (для того, чтобы в одной таблице хранить все виды контактной информации - адреса, телефоны, e-mail и др.), поэтому и запрос будет посложнее. Приведу пример получения телефона контрагента для конфигурации УПП 1.3:

```
Запрос = Новый Запрос("ВЫБРАТЬ
|   Контрагенты.Ссылка КАК Контрагент,
|   КонтактнаяИнформация.Представление КАК Телефон
|ИЗ
|   Справочник.Контрагенты КАК Контрагенты
|       ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ РегистрСведений.КонтактнаяИнформация КАК КонтактнаяИнформация
|       ПО (КонтактнаяИнформация.Объект = Контрагенты.Ссылка)
|           И (КонтактнаяИнформация.Тип = &ТипКонтактнойИнформации)
|           И (КонтактнаяИнформация.Вид = &ВидКонтактнойИнформации)
|ГДЕ
|   Контрагенты.Ссылка = &Ссылка");
Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("ТипКонтактнойИнформации", Перечисления.ТипыКонтактнойИнформации.Телефон);
Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("ВидКонтактнойИнформации", Справочники.ВидыКонтактнойИнформации.ТелефонКонтрагента);

РезультатЗапроса = Запрос.Выполнить().Выбрать();
Если РезультатЗапроса.Следующий() Тогда
    Телефон = РезультатЗапроса.Телефон;
КонецЕсли;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. То что нужно